# Selection StartContainer in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, selection, range

I have a selection object where in IE, I run

```
range = selection.createRange();
```

I then try to get the startContainer but am unable to figure out how. All examples show me SETTING the startContainer, but I am basing this off highlighting text. How do I know which element to set it to without getting it first?

I know in FireFox it's as simple as

```
range     = selection.getRangeAt(0);
firstNode = range.startContainer;
```

Answer (score 2):

[Its been two years.]
Ok this is going to be ugly, but I think I got the answer to this question (Seems to work on IE8). The code is as follows (Explanation is within comments):

```
/**
 * @param {window object} win The window from which the selection is to be retrieved. This could also be an iframe.contentWindow.
 */
function getRangeObject(win) { //Gets the first range object. 
    win=win || window;
    if (win.getSelection) { // W3C/FF/Chrome/Safari/Opera/IE9
        return win.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);    //W3C DOM Range Object
    }
    else if(win.document.selection) { // IE8
        return win.document.selection.createRange(); //Microsoft TextRange Object
    }
    return null;
}

function getStartContainer(win) {
win=win || window;
    var range=getRangeObject(win);
    if(range) {
        if(range.startContainer) { // W3C/FF/Chrome/Safari/Opera/IE9
            return range.startContainer;
        } else if(document.selection) { //IE8
            var rangeCopy=range.duplicate(); //Create a copy
            var rangeObj=range.duplicate();

            rangeCopy.collapse(true); //Go to beginning of the selection
        rangeCopy.moveEnd('character',1); //Select only the first character
            //Debug Message
            //alert(rangeCopy.text); //Should be the first character of the selection
            var parentElement=rangeCopy.parentElement();
            rangeObj.moveToElementText(parentElement); //Select all text of parentElement
            rangeObj.setEndPoint('EndToEnd',rangeCopy); //Set end point to the first character of the 'real' selection
            var text=rangeObj.text; //Now we get all text from parentElement's first character upto the real selection's first character

            //Iterate through all the child text nodes and check for matches
            //As we go through each text node keep removing the text value (substring) from the beginning of the text variable.
            var container=null;
            for(var node=parentElement.firstChild; node; node=node.nextSibling) {
                if(node.nodeType==3) {//Text node
                    var find=node.nodeValue;
                    var pos=text.indexOf(find);
                    if(pos==0 && text!=find) { //text==find is a special case
                        text=text.substring(find.length);
                    } else {
                        container=node;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            range.startContainer=container; //Finally we are here
            //Debug Message
            //alert(container.nodeValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for the excessive comments (I think it was needed). Once you remove all those comments you get code which is...less ugly :P.

Comment: Wow, great idea! Tnx a fortune!

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this problem. I can't find an elegant solution so here is an inelegant one:

Note: It will ONLY work if the start container has an id

First check if the browser is IE. Then,

```
            // var range should be your TextRange object
            var matches = range.htmlText.match(/<[^>]* id=([^\s]+)[^>]*>/);
            if (matches) {
                var startContainer = document.getElementById(matches[1]);
                if (startContainer) {
                    ...
                }
            }
```

Here are the methods on the range: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535872(v=vs.85).aspx

I don't see any way to get an actual set of dom objs.

Answer (score -1):

I'm also working on something similar. I haven't gotten to the IE part just yet, but I would suggest iterating through the list of properties of range and see what's available to you

```
var msg = '';
for (var i in range) {
    msg += i + ': ' + range[i] + '\n';
}
alert(msg);
```